# compare 2 string in jave with special character

Tags: java

how to compare 2 string with special character?
I have the string as below, may I know how to compare both?

```
strA = "AC-11234X-DD+++1"
strB = "AC-11234X-DD+++1"
```

I tested `matches()`, `equals()`, `equalsIgnoreCase()` all not working.

```
if (strA.matches(strB)){
...
} else {
..
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("AC-11234X-DD+++1".equals("AC-11234X-DD+++1"));` prints `true`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There are no *special* characters here.. `equals()` will do the job

Comment: Working with equals here.

Comment: `==`, `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` all return true. `matches` expect valid regex which will throw exception.

Comment: equal not working, i tested already. I set when equal, then need to print something.. but it keep jump to not equal.

Comment: @user3522363 no it will work.please recheck your code

Comment: The only way I can think of that this wouldn't work is if one of the Strings contains a character that we can't *see*, and that hasn't been copied into the Strings in your post. I suggest you `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strA.getBytes())); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strB.getBytes()));` - that might make it easier to see if the Strings are genuinely different.

Comment: If you are using Java8 then consider adding to your question result of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strA.chars().toArray()));` for `strA` and `strB`. If you don't have Java8 post result of `System.out.println(charIndexes(strA));` where code of `charIndexes` is `public static List<Integer> charIndexes(String str){List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); for (char c: str.toCharArray()) list.add((int)c); return list;}`

Comment: Just in case, you can update your question with new informations by using [[edit]] option placed below your question.

Answer (score -1):

This code checks if those two strings are equal or not

```
String strA = "AC-11234X-DD+++1" ;
String strB = "AC-11234X-DD+++1";    

if(strA.equals(strB))
       //they are equal
else
       //they are not
```

Comment: I am not sure you read the question, the OP explicitly says `equals()` doesn't work for him, need to first understand *why*, but he has tried it already.

Comment: @amit I read the question the strings are identical so he/she can use the equals method to check if the strings are equal to one another, i dont see a need to your compareTo or anything else :)

Answer (score -1):

why dont you try for

System.out.println(strA.hashCode()==strB.hashCode());

if matches(), equals(), equalsIgnoreCase() are not working.

incase you are not satisfied with this result also, you could try to overwrite the compareTo method and have your own logic.

Comment: Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique, they can be same for different strings like `"Aa"` and `"BB"` so `strA.hashCode()==strB.hashCode()` is not best approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String strA = "AC-11234X-DD+++1";
    String strB = "AC-11234X-DD+++1";

    System.out.println(strA.equals(strB));
    }
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: [Are “works for me” answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Answer (score -1):

Must use the *compareTo* method.

The value returned by this method is an *int*:

- if it is > 0 means that the second string precedes the first in alphabetical order
- if it is = 0 means that two string are equal;
- if it is < 0 means that the fisrt string precedes the second in alphabetical order

An example (very rough) about your problem might be this:

```
int r = A.compareTo(B);

if(r > 0) { 
  System.out.println("B comes before A in alphabetical order");
} else if(r < 0) {
  System.out.println("A comes before B string in alphabetical order");
} else {
  System.out.println("The two strings are equal");
}
```

Comment: "*Must use the compareTo method.*" why? This should work with `equals` if strings would be equal, There is no need for `compareTo`.